# Does a notification message count towards the collapse_key limit?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

As per the [Firebase Notification docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages):

> Notification messages are always collapsible.

I was trying to figure out if they have some intrinsic `collapse_key`. And if so, does that count towards the `collapse_key` limit of 4 per device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. All the notifications sent from the Web Console are collapsible.

Which means they have an implicit `collapse_key`

If a device has a pending-to-be-delivered messages from the Web Console,
 this implicit `collapse_key` counts towards the limit of 4 per device.

Comment: There seems to be a bug about that. In my case, when the device is offline and then gets back online, I receive all notifications that have the same `collapse_key`. Not just 4 of them. Please check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552291/fcm-notifications-and-collapse-key

Comment: @MScott please contact firebase support with more information to help the firebase team debugging it.

Comment: It looks like the implicit collapse key is currently the package name of the app.