# Adding collapse_key in FCM

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is the `collapse_key` needed for Android and iOS push notifications? If I specify `collapse_key` in payload, will FCM use it? Or it will add another `collapse_key`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the `collapse_key` needed for Android and iOS push notifications?

No, it is not needed, unless you *do* want to use it, then of course you would use it. This depends on whether you want the messages to be collapsible (meaning that the notification may be 'overwritten' in a sense, by another similar message with the same `collapse_key` value.

> If I specify `collapse_key` in payload, will fcm use it?

Yes, assuming you don't go over the four-key limit. You choose whatever string value you want to be used as the key and FCM will use it. If, however, you have more than four keys, you will get un-expected behavior. You won't know which keys will work properly in that case.

> Or will it add another `collapse_key`

No Sir.

Comment: It's also good to know that if a Notification payload is used and no `collapse_key` is specified, an implicit `collapse_key` will be used. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39682968/4625829).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. actually there was a collapse_key added in data section in my fcm payload, that's why fcm was not using this and was adding it's own.

Comment: Not a problem. If my answers helped to answer your three questions you could select it as the answer, otherwise it was still a pleasure to help!

Comment: I am trying to use a collapse_key: "follow" like so but it is still showing notifications with the same collapse key independently and does not overwrite previous ones... any thoughts am I doing something counter-intuitive? Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923777/firebase-sending-multiple-push-notifications-instead-of-stacking-or-replacing