# How to sort by children key value in firebase?

Tags: android, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to sort projects based on the dateAdded:

The tree looks like this:

```
projects: {
    "someprojectId": {
       dateAdded: Firebase.TimeStamp
    },

    "someProjectid2":{
      dateAdded: Firebase.Timestamp
   }

}
```

I am calling it like so in android:

```
mDatabase.child("projects").orderByChild("dateAdded").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

However, it is not sorting it correctly, or at all for that matter of fact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would help to see how you actually handle the data in `onDataChange`. But my guess is that you're failing to loop over the children:

```
mDatabase
  .child("projects")
  .orderByChild("dateAdded")
  .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(child.getKey());
      }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it works I did not realize it groups them in ascending order had to add limitToLast to show the most recent first. Thanks.

Comment: ok, I was wondering if you knew the answer to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205388/how-to-grab-multiple-paths-and-sort-them-and-bring-back-the-result-in-firebase Also, since I noticed you work for Firebase not sure if you know the issue I am having here as well with the collapseKey http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923777/firebase-sending-multiple-push-notifications-instead-of-stacking-or-replacing   Appreciate it, a big firebase fan here.