# How to sort Firebase Keys in ascending order?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a list of products in my Firebase Database. My SKU looks like this `c08p10`. But the problem is that Hundred product is shown after the tenth product.

Please refer the screenshot for the jumbled product order.

[image]

I can understand that the products are arranging alphabetically. But how can i display the products in the below order

```
c08p10
c08p11
c08p12
```

**NOTE**

I can populate the data in a List view or recycler View. But the products are arranged in the firebase DB order. If I try to reverse the order. It gives the below structure.

```
c08p118
c08p117
c08p116
```

Comment: Refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198291/how-to-sort-by-children-key-value-in-firebase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase keys are strings. And when you order string data, it is ordered lexicographically.

So for numbers, this is the normal order:

- 1
- 9
- 10
- 11

But for strings, this is the normal order:

- "1"
- "11"
- "19"
- "9"

There is no operator in Firebase (nor in most other databases) to change this behavior. Instead, you will have to modify the data to get the behavior you want. So: store values that are in the order you need them when sorted lexicographically. For numbers you can accomplish that by padding them with zeroes:

- "001"
- "009"
- "011"
- "019"

Or in your case `c09p010`, etc.