# Firebase realtime query startAt and endAt not working as intended on a joint property

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a joint property for querying multiple values at a time. It looks like this:

[image]

And here's my querying code:

```
rootRef.child("leagues")
            .orderByChild("division_size")
            .startAt("1_1")
            .endAt("1_10")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        log.error("League Available")
                    } else {
                        log.error("League Not Available")
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    log.error("Failed to read value.", error.toException())
                }
            })
```

Notice the size in "division_size" of startAt is 1 and endAt is 10. This is giving me incorrect result, the snapshot doesn't exist when I do that but when I switch the size of endAt to 9 or any single digit then it works.

How can I make it to work on all digits, lets say from 1 to 100?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because of the way strings sort in [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).  Strings don't consider any sort of numeric values when sorting, even if the strings might contain a number.  They just look at the UTF-8 (or ascii) values of the individual characters.  Your division size strings sort like this:

1. 1_1
2. 1_10
3. 1_2
4. 1_21
5. ...
6. 1_9

See the pattern?  The third character is being sorted by is ascii value, not by the embedded number's value.

I suggest using a different system to sort your database children that takes only numbers into account and not strings.  Since I don't know the properties of your division_size strings, it's hard to recommend something.  But I think you can figure out what you need to do instead (and again, it won't involve strings, just numbers, probably in different child values).

Comment: I see. I now just have to know in advance how many of those there will be and add 0s before them if theyre less than the amount of digits. Something like: "001_001"

Comment: That is correct. Also see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275688/how-to-sort-firebase-keys-in-ascending-order/43279836#43279836