# How to Query Data from Firebase to get biggest value first and smallest value last?

Tags: java, android

i try to get values for my Recyclerview ordered By a timestamp.
My Firebase DatabaseStructure looks like the following:

```
 "connections" : {
    "matches" : {
      "ZYpiuLBRJkcM1cK6tDctKYva7UB3" : {
        "ChatId" : "-LG6GS394d_1NotmhnrD",
        "lastMsg" : "i wasdsffas asydfhjdadsfoing just fu?an before i met you ok dir?",
        "lastMsgBy" : "6dB5rWfSIwez3gO0N0ClBwFJKu53",
        "state" : "active",
        "ts" : 4
      },
      "vhsIe0nBBWQ0D9csBpLwgL4Mf293" : {
        "ChatId" : "-LG9_RZNm0DgxlhaMaCv",
        "lastMsg" : "jj?hjkjäooasASDfsdafasdf? a!?",
        "lastMsgBy" : "6dB5rWfSIwez3gO0N0ClBwFJKu53",
        "state" : "active",
        "ts" : 5
      }
```

to order it by the child ts i created the following:

```
 private void getMyMatchesQuery(final String userId, final String profileImageUrl, final String name){
  final String userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
  final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid).child("connections").child("matches").child(userId);
  Query qi = ref.orderByChild("ts");
  qi.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                System.out.println("123value"+dataSnapshot.child("lastMsg").getValue().toString() + dataSnapshot.child("ts").getValue().toString());
            }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

 }
```

unfortunately i receive always the first value of the databse , it seems like the method doesnt take care about the ts value. Maybe someone knows out how to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort by children key value in firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198291/how-to-sort-by-children-key-value-in-firebase)

Comment: nope because i tried this solution without success